# Multiple user authentication in flask

Tags: python, database, sqlite, authentication, flask

I wanted to create a authentication system in python flask which allows user to register and the system will serve them their own content that they stored in the database.

How I can do this using sqllite3 and flask ? What will be my approach?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ for authentication

Then, use the user name or ID to query the database for the appropriate content.

Answer (score 0):

On a basic level you can use is

1. Database (SQLite3)
2. UUID or any unique identification (for unique identification)
3. Build a basic route where the user can check if the user - password matches with the user in the database.

Flask has an inbuilt library for handling login sessions.  https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

For more reference: 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aTnmsDMldY 
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/login-and-registration-project-using-flask-and-mysql/